# How to split list of arrays into individual arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I got one list of arrays with two different dimensions arrays inside.

```
 c = [array([  3.00493560e+05,   3.04300000e+01,   3.21649837e-01,
         6.50984546e+05,   3.00493379e+05,   3.03073203e+01]), array([ 14.])]
```

I want to split them based on there dimensions to have two separate arrays.

```
   a =  array[([  3.00493560e+05,   3.04300000e+01,   3.21649837e-01,
                 6.50984546e+05,   3.00493379e+05,   3.03073203e+01]]

   b = array[([ 14.])]
```

I tried to use np.split(c, 6) - but it splits array based and given length and creates one big array so it's not what i am expecting.

I also tried to use

```
a = c[c[:, 0] < 1.5]
b = c[c[:, 1] > 5]
```

It works but sometimes my value from second array have same values as values from first array...

Comment: How about - `a,b = [i for i in c]`? Or `a,b = [[i] for i in c]`?

Comment: You seem to want two separate things at the same time: you want to split a tuple and filter array values. Could you be more specific?

Comment: @Divakar i tried your method but it throwing me error: "iteration over a 0-d array". I guess is because i use np.asarray to build my arrays.

Comment: @ma3oun i just want to split this two arrays, nothing more.

Comment: Well first off the sample you have provided us is a list of arrays, not an array. So, maybe produce a more representative version of your data.

Comment: @Divakar your right its a list of array.

Comment: What's wrong with `a,b=c`?  `c` is a 2 element list.  It can unpack into 2 variables.  OK, your `a` and `b` don't look like normal lists or arrays,with a bad mx of [] and ().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, you wish to split a list of numpy arrays into individual python lists. You can do the following:

```
a,b = [ [individualArray] for individualArray in c]
```

This will give you the desired output:

```
a= [array([  3.00493560e+05,   3.04300000e+01,   3.21649837e-01,
             6.50984546e+05,   3.00493379e+05,   3.03073203e+01]
b= [array([ 14.])]
```

**EDIT**

In case c contains more than 2 arrays, you can generalize this approach by generating a list of split arrays:

```
splitArraysList = [ [individualArray] for individualArray in c ]
```

If the arrays are very big, you can use a generator instead of a list, to iterate on the individual arrays in the split list:

```
splitArraysList = ( [individualArray] for individualArray in c )
```

Comment: Thank you it works nice for small data. But i am getting error: "too many values to unpack (expected 2)".

Comment: Ok now i got one big array containing 
 [[ array([  3.00514850e+05,   3.32400000e+01,   2.71669002e-01,
         6.50974961e+05,   3.00515112e+05,   3.32248995e+01])
  array([ 15.])]. 

Sorry is my fault. My inputs is a list of arrays not one big array as i thought.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you want is something like this:

```
a = sum([i for i in c if len(i) == 6], [])
b = sum([i for i in c if len(i) == 1], [])
```

If what you want is for `a` to be all lists with a length of 6, and `b` to be all list with a length of 1